# Перенести данные на другую страницу

Tags: php

```
на странице index.php есть данные в таблице получены методом POST, как эти данные перенести на другую страницу при нажатии на кнопку перехода

<table border="1" align="center">   
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['view'])){          
?>
<tr>
<td width="70px"><?=$_POST['udk']?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><pre>№ <?=$_POST['author_single']?></pre></td>
<td><?=mb_strtoupper($_POST['initial'],'utf-8')?></td>
<td><?=$_POST['author1']?></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6"><p style="text-indent: 25px;"><?=$_POST['anotazia']?></p></td>
</tr>
 <form action="kartka.php" method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="версия для печати">
</form>
<?php
}
 ?>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

создавай input type="hidden" и дублируй туда данные, при нажитии на "версия для печати" данные отпрявятся снова

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="<?=$_POST['udk']?>"> это типо так делается?